# R function to generate random integers with predefined mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, simulation, data-generation

Does anybody know a function custom or not, to generate random integers following (as a whole set) a predefined mean and standard deviation?

For example I'd like to be able to generate a set of 5 integer that will have a mean of 2.8 and standard deviation of 2.4 and consist of values from a 0 to 6 range:

```
function(N=5, M=2.8, SD=2.4, range=0:6)
> 0 1 3 6 4
```

I found posts that relate to random integers summing to a given value: [Generate N random integers that sum to M in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845909/generate-n-random-integers-that-sum-to-m-in-r) but I couldn't figure out how to reuse it for my case scenario

Comment: Your problem isn't sufficiently defined. I'm also having trouble imagining a sensible application for this.

Comment: What did I miss? Given a 1) number (N) of elements, 2) possible values range 3) mean (M), 4) standard deviation (SD) - generate a set of N integers from a specified range that will follow a normal distribution with M and SD. Now that I think about it - Im looking for a `rnorm` function for integers with specified range (min / max) only

Comment: So, you are looking for the truncated normal distribution? That's confusing because you seem to describe a discrete distribution in your question.

Comment: Forgive my lack of clarity - after looking into both distributions I'd say that I'm looking for a mix o both - truncated normal in the sense that I want to be able to bound both min and max values; and discrete in the sense that I want only integers (positive, but can be negative as well)

Comment: OK, so you want a truncated discrete distribution? Which distribution family?

Comment: I really don't know how to answer. Is there a one, that fits best to how I described the result?

Comment: You need to consult a statistician. They can help you defining your problem. Once you have a clear problem definition, solving this should become easy.

Comment: If Gaussian makes sense, than that's it

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. You claim to want a discrete distribution and Gaussian is continuous.

Comment: I'm reading about this and I'm still confused by the complexity here. I want to generate a set of integers from a defined range of minimum and maximum that will  have a specified mean and standard deviation. When I think "mean and SD" i think of a normal distribution, that in this case can take only whole numbers.